# Dwork's theory on periods and points counting of elliptic curves.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

The Legendre family of elliptic curves is defined by
\begin{equation}
y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda).
\end{equation}
The integration of the algebraic one-form $dx/y$ (up to a nonzero multiple) is given by the hypergeometric series
\begin{equation}
F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\lambda)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}^2 \lambda^j.
\end{equation}
From the theory of Dwork, we can counts the points of elliptic curves using this period. More precisely, for an odd prime number $p$, we define a new power series 
\begin{equation}
U(\lambda)=F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\lambda)/F(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\lambda^p).
\end{equation}
Dwork showed that $U(t)$ can be analytically continued to a function defined in the $p$-adic radius $\geq 1$. While if $\lambda_0 \in\mathbb{F}_p-\{0,1\}$, let $1-a(\lambda_0)T+pT^2$ be the numerator of the zeta function of the elliptic curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda_0)$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
1-a(\lambda_0)T+pT^2=(1-U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0))~T)(1-(p/U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0)))~T),
\end{equation}
which implies $$a(\lambda_0)=U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0))+(p/U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0)))$$
Here $\text{Teich}(\lambda_0)$ is the Teichmuller representative of $\lambda_0$.

Use Mathematica, it is very easy to evaluate the first $1000$ terms of the power series $U(\lambda)$. The choose a $\lambda_0$, we can also compute the $p$-adic expansion of its Teichmuller representative, say to the order $p^{50}$. Then I plug $\text{Teich}(\lambda_0)+O(p^{51})$ into $U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0))+(p/U(\text{Teich}(\lambda_0)))+O(\lambda^{1001})$, it does not converge to $a(\lambda_0)$ $p$-adicly. I have tried several prime numbers.

Does anyone know why? Do I understand the theory incorrectly?

Comment: You didn't expose the theory. The first step is to transform $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x-1)(x-\lambda)}}$ into elliptic integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-m^2\sin^2\phi}}$, expand this into an analytic function of $m$, then use the properties of the isomorphism complex torus to elliptic curve (given by the Weierstrass function) to relate it to some τ such that  $\lambda=\lambda(\tau)$ (the modular lambda function), then extend the corresponding analytic functions to the p-adics,

Comment: then find an endomorphism $\phi$ of the p-adic elliptic curve whose reduction modulo p is the Froebenius $(x,y)\to (x^p,y^p)$. It lifts to an endomorphism on the complex torus side, when $\lambda$ is a root of unity it satisfies $\phi(\tau(\lambda))=\tau(\lambda^p)$, and $\phi(\tau)/\tau$ is a root of the Frobenius minimal polynomial : what you called $U(Teich(\lambda))$

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much. Do you know of any references to this theory?